# Youtube Player API controls hide for Android

Tags: android, youtube-api

I want to use only pause, play & seek_bar of youtube API in the Android app but it gives only 3 type of default controls.in default it shows setting button, does anyone have an idea how to remove that setting button coz it let the user go to youtube app and I don't want to let the user know about my channel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does anyone have an idea how to remove that setting button?

According to this [Android Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle) Document,you could use **YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL** to only display the play, pause and seek bar.

> Summary:
>
> Enum values
>
> **YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS** :    A style that shows no
> interactive player controls.
>
> **YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT** :   The
> default style, showing all interactive controls.
>
> **YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL** :   A minimal style, showing only a time
> bar and play/pause controls.

Comment: yes...but I am not able to seek the video to the specific time. I want just to play, pause and seek bar to seek video..like forwarding video.

Comment: I am facing the same problem can you tell me how to make custom controls